# What is the theoretical explanation of the flow of this try-catch in JS? My teacher doesn't how to know explain it

Tags: javascript, arrays, try-catch, minesweeper

I have made a primitive 5x5 version of a minesweeper with two 2D arrays, it works perfectly but I have theoretical doubts:

- **Array1** is a template: there I put a 1 where I want a mine, 0 where there isn't one.
- In **array2** I “draw” everything from Array1: each cell shows how many mines there are in the 8 cells around it, controlling this through if conditions.

The problem I had is that when I was at an corner, I got an 'Uncaught TypeError' because the cell was undefined (normal, there is no value and it is outside the array), so I decided caught the errors to try to solve the problem and EUREKA! Works!

1. **First question:** when handling the error in the catch, it seems that it returns to the try (it does not continue, but goes to the next line of code in its try). Why? In Java I think it doesn't work like that.
2. **Second question:** I had to use two try-catch, one to detect
   mines in previous rows and one for subsequent rows. It gave me an
   error if I put everything in the same try. Why? Its the same error. Interestingly, the
   if's on the same line (array1[i]) do not give me an error, I think
   itmay be because I do calculations like array1[i-1] or array1[i+2].

First of all, I'm a beginner and I appreciate your help. Sorry if I'm making silly mistakes or my logic is not correct.

```
    array1 = new Array();

array1[0] = new Array(0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
array1[1] = new Array(0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
array1[2] = new Array(0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
array1[3] = new Array(0, 1, 0, 0, 1);
array1[4] = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);



let array2 = new Array();

array2[0] = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
array2[1] = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
array2[2] = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
array2[3] = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
array2[4] = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);


let cont = 0;

//Row loop ARRAY1
for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {

    //Column loop ARRAY1
    for (let j = 0; j < array1[i].length; j++) {

        /*Current cell: It goes through cell by cell of ARRAY1, if a 1 (MINA) is found,
         an X is drawn in ARRAY2 (same position)*/

        if (array1[i][j] == 1) {

            array2[i].splice(j, 1, 'x');

        } else {


            //Current row

            if (array1[i][j - 1] == 1) { cont++; }
            if (array1[i][j + 1] == 1) { cont++; }


           try {

                //+1 Row
                if (array1[i + 1][j - 1] == 1) { cont++; }
                if (array1[i + 1][j] == 1) { cont++; }
                if (array1[i + 1][j + 1] == 1) { cont++; }


            } catch (e) {}

           try {

                //-1 Row
                if (array1[i - 1][j - 1] == 1) { cont++; }
                if (array1[i - 1][j] == 1) { cont++; }
                if (array1[i - 1][j + 1] == 1) { cont++; }

            } catch (e) {} 


            array2[i].splice(j, 1, cont);
            cont = 0;

        }

    }

}

console.log(array2);
```

Comment: You may: 1) put each `if( array... == 1)` in a `try ... catch` statement 2) use actual guards `if (i < array1.length -1 && j > 0 && array1[i + 1][j - 1] == 1)` 3) use the optional chaining operator `if (array1[i + 1]?.[j - 1] == 1) { cont++; }`

Comment: And the semantics of `try ... catch` is the same as in java; after an error occurs, the next statements inside that `try` block are not executed, execution moves to the `catch` block (which does nothing in your example) and then to the next statement after that `catch`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried all the options you told me, it ended up working with real guards (although otherwise I still don't understand why it worked perfectly with try-cath when in theory it couldn't be)

Comment: You're welcome. If you're really curious about why it worked, run the code in a debugger, or add statements like `console.log("A", {i, j});`, `console.log("B", {i, j});`, ... in (to begin with, one, than more) `try` statements, at the beginning, after each statement and in the `catch` branch, to follow what's happening exactly.